# 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable on Python

Tags: python

```
result=[]
taken=[]
for i in range(len(pos[0])):
    taken.append[pos[0][i]]
```

I get not subscriptable error on the 'taken.append'. I declared taken as an empty array, but the it seems like the computer took it as an int.

Comment: try  taken.append(pos[0][i])

Comment: The brackets are for subscripting. Use parentheses when calling taken.append.

Comment: Wow I didnt see that. Thank you!